# Bound on scaling mixed quantum-classical computer designs

Tags: quantum-circuit, complexity-theory

I am familiar with some basics of quantum computation and this makes me wonder, are there any upper bounds known on the size of a quantum circuit, such that quantum circuit + some classical circuit, can simulate any quantum algorithm within some standard time/space complexity bound? Be it in the realm of polynomial or quantum computers.
Some forms I am wondering about are as follows:

Given q-qubits; an r-bit classical random access memory and a g quantum gates. Is there ?, such that BQ?(f(x)) = ?(f(x)) and the q and g can be bounded? Such that ? here would stand for PTIME/EXPTIME/PSPACE/EXPSPACE etc. Are there any positive or negative results of this form?